# Coset of $[18]$ in $\Bbb Z_{55}/11\Bbb Z_{55}?$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

**Q:** Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{55}$, $H=11\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ and $g=18\pmod{55}.$ Write down the elements of the left coset $gH$ as a comma-separated list of elements of $G$.

---

My thoughts: First find $G=\mathbb{Z}_{55}$, then $H=11\mathbb{Z}_{55}$, then $gH=18+11\mathbb{Z}_{55}$. Thus, $H=\mathbb{Z}_{55}=\{0,11,22,33,44,55\equiv0\}\implies gH=\{18,29,40,51,7\} (\mod55)$, whereby I simply multiplied all elements of of $H$ by $g=18\mod55$.

However, I also realise that since $aK=K\iff a\in K$ for some group $K$, so $\dots$ $11\in\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ and $18\in H\implies\mathbb{Z}_{55}=11\mathbb{Z}_{55}\implies gH=H=\mathbb{Z}_{55}$??? (Set of 55 elements!??)

Comment: $\{7, 18, 29, 40,51\}$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The coset is $$[18]+11\Bbb Z_{55},$$ and not $11\Bbb Z_{55}$ (nor $18\cdot 11\Bbb Z_{55}$) because the operation of $\Bbb Z_{55}$ is addition, not multiplication. Note that $11\mid 55$.

> It looks like you got it right the first time. It's just that you wrote it mutliplicatively instead of additively. Also, $18\notin H$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite following; so is $11\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ supposed to be all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ with $11$ added to all elements?

Comment: No, @JasonXu. The elements of $11\Bbb Z_{55}$ are of the form $[11a]$ for $a\in\{0,1,2,\dots, 54\}=:I$. But $$[18]+11\Bbb Z_{55}=\{[18+11a]\mid a\in I\}.$$

Comment: You're getting the coset and the group you're quotienting by mixed up, @JasonXu.

Comment: Do you know what happens in $\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z$, @JasonXu?

Comment: Am not sure what the significance is...  isn't ℤ/11ℤ just the set {0,...,10}?

Comment: Not quite, @JasonXu. Its elements are of the form $$\begin{align}[a]_{11}&:=\{b\in \Bbb Z: 11\mid b-a\}\\ &=\{b\in\Bbb Z: b-a\in 11\Bbb Z\}\\ &=\{b\in\Bbb Z:a+11\Bbb Z=b+11\Bbb Z\}\\ &=a+11\Bbb Z,\end{align}$$ where $11\Bbb Z=\{11x:x\in\Bbb Z\}.$

Comment: I am even more confused now. So, is it all $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{55}$ multiplied by $11\mod55$?

Comment: I apologise; I am quite new to group theory in general, and my modular arithmetic/number theory knowledge is quite elementary at the moment too

Comment: That's okay, @JasonXu. Think about it for a while. Not everyone gets it right away. Here $H=11\Bbb Z_{55}$ is all elements of $\Bbb Z_{55}$ multiplied by $11$. Notice that there is some repetition modulo $55$. On the other hand, $[18]+11\Bbb Z_{55}=[18]+H$ is all elements of $H$, each plus $18$ modulo $55$.

Comment: Ah, so my first method was indeed correct. I've changed the $\cdot$ to $\add$ to reflect the addition; your initial reply makes sense now :)